# Mysql, linux, autocompletion

Tags: mysql, linux

I need autocompletion for mysql console in Linux.

I found this solution.

Add this to .my.cnf. file in home folder.

```
[mysql]
auto-rehash
```

But it doesn't work, for ubuntu 19.04 and mysql 14.14.

And just one question, is it possible to do it for small characters? I mean 'select' instead 'SELECT', etc.

Thank you.

Comment: `14.14` is not a MySQL version number.  Maybe `5.7` or `8.0`?

Comment: You can always use `select` instead of `SELECT`.  Ditto for other keywords.  Auto-complete does not apply to keywords (I don't think).

Comment: You could also try [mycli](http://mycli.net)

Comment: @danblack Thank you, seems this is best solution.

Answer (score 0):

[auto-rehash](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_auto-rehash) is database, table and column completion. It isn't a generic syntax completion aid.